# Consecutive zeros in decimal expansion of $\pi$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

Is it known whether or not there exist arbitrarily long sequences of consecutive zeros in the decimal expansion of $\pi$?

Comment: No, this is not known.  However, known results about the irrationality measure of $\pi$ imply that a large string of consecutive zeroes cannot occur *extremely* early in the decimal expansion (the bound here is far, far weaker than would be expected from a random sequence of digits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is "known" but not known.  It is "known" because $\pi$ is expected to be normal.  Almost all reals are and there is no known reason for $\pi$ not to be.  Being normal implies (among many other things) that sequences of zeros occur at their statistical expectation-that a string of $n$ zeros will occur on average every $10^{n}$ digits.  But the normality of $\pi$ has not been proven.

Answer (score 2):

There are conjectures saying so. The result is unknown. Anyway, taking a random number in every interval without preference, you find such a number with probability one. There are known nombers with such a property, such as the [Champernowne constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant)